# Python convert tuple to array

Tags: python, list

How can I convert at 3-Dimensinal tuple into an array

```
a = []
a.append((1,2,4))
a.append((2,3,4))
```

in a array like:

```
b = [1,2,4,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Your listing shows a list of tuples (vaguely 2D-ish)

Comment: How do i just get the first element ? like b = [1,2]

Comment: @Samy `b[:2]` gets [1,2]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append((1,2,4))
>>> a.append((2,3,4))
>>> [x for xs in a for x in xs]
[1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4]
```

Using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
[1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 14):

The simple way, use [extend](http://www.python.org/doc//current/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method.

```
x = []
for item in a:
    x.extend(item)
```

Answer (score 9):

If you mean array as in numpy array, you can also do:

```
a = []
a.append((1,2,4))
a.append((2,3,4))
a = np.array(a)
a.flatten()
```